# Check csv file column value and compare it to a threshold using Python

Tags: python, csv

I am attempting to read a csv file (it just has one row) and compare certain columns to a set threshold.

This csv file has a number of readings from an antenna and the threshold I have will let the user know whether a signal is present or not.

I can import the csv or just the particular rows but cant figure out the IF section

For example

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('710_1_capture.csv', usecols=[12])
print (df1)
```

IF xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx > -30:
    do an action

Any help you can provide will be gratefully received

Answer (score 0):

I don't the form of print (df1)  this really help but
why dont try to convert the csv file to a list and then  make a for loop where check for your threshold???

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('flpth/to/file.csv')

new_df = df[df['ClmName']>=blah]) & (df['ClmName2']==blah2])]
```

variables can be strings or numbers.  You can also use the `.isin` method. [link](http://Indexing%20and%20selecting%20data)